# Rails date conversion, invalid date error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am POSTing data to my Rails API, one of the fields to be set on the created record looks like this:

```
{
  "sign_date": "04/13/2015"
}
```

In my Rails API, I'm formatting it like so prior to the data being inserted:

```
Date.strptime(params[:sign_date], "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

However, Rails is spitting back an obscure `Invalid Date` error.  Must the data be of the type `Date` to create the record and have the date set properly?

What's wrong here?

Comment: Are sure that you have expected value in params[:sign_date]? You can use 'pry' or 'debugger' to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get that error when I accidentally try to parse an empty string - check that your parameters are coming through correctly and where you expect them.

```
> Date.strptime('', '%m/%d/%Y')
ArgumentError: invalid date
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work,

Try it in **Rails Console**.

```
Time.strptime("04/13/2015", "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

#Output

"2015-04-13"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`Date.strptime(params["sign_date"], "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`

For more details check [Hash with indifferent access](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html)